# Multiple conditions in regex - how to replace both colon and space with dash

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace both colon and space with dash in regex?
Here's what I've managed to do: 
to replace space: `replace(/\s+/g, '-')`, 
to replace colon: `replace(/:\s+/g, '-')`. 
How do I merge these expressions?

Comment: Can you add some example input and expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an alternation `[ :]`

```js
var input = "Hello World:Goodbye";
console.log(input);
input = input.replace(/[ :]+/g, '-');
console.log(input);
```

Note that this replaces actual *spaces*, not all whitespace characters, which your original version using `\s` does.

Comment: I don't think this is merging two regexs because only matches for single white space.

Comment: @MaheerAli What do think the `g` flag does?  `g` stands for globally, i.e. anywhere in the input string.

Comment: `replace(/\s+/g, '-')` replaces two or more white spaces with single `-` but your code don't it creates as much `-` as much there are white spaces

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var text = "hello: hey"
console.log(text.replace(/(:|\s+)/g, "-"))
```

Returns "hello--hey"